# Hive - Get number of rows, total size resulted in a query

Tags: hadoop, hive

​I have a query(ex: below) for which I want to get the statistics like how many rows it results, what is the size of a row.

```
SELECT t1.c1 ,t1.c2 FROM t1 WHERE NOT (t1.c1 IS NULL );
```

Is there any way to get it?
I tried "explain extended" as below, which is not printing the details that I want.

```
Explain Extended SELECT t1.c1 ,t1.c2 FROM t1 WHERE NOT (t1.c1 IS NULL );
```

Please note I need the statistics on a query not on a table. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would insert the result set into a temporary table and then look for the desired statistics in it

Comment: Information you are looking for is not stored ready anywhere in hive as now. 
Still stats has to computed